# Including a dependency from MavenRepository in my POM, do I need to put its dependencies in my POM?

Tags: java, maven

I'm adding jersey to my project:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/1.18.1
```

do I need to add dependencies to my POM for items found in: "This artifact depends on ..."?

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to add dependencies to my POM for items found in: "This
>   artifact depends on ..."?

No, You don't need to add transitive dependencies. Maven will handle it.

> Transitive dependencies are a new feature in Maven 2.0. This allows
>   you to avoid needing to discover and specify the libraries that your
>   own dependencies require, and including them automatically.

Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) for more details